# Python tkinter Combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I want to fill my entries when I click in a name of my Combobox without buttons like 'check' to show the values. How can i do that?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

root = tk.Tk()
cb = ttk.Combobox(root,state='readonly')
labName = ttk.Label(root,text='Names: ')
labTel = ttk.Label(root,text='TelNum:')
labCity = ttk.Label(root,text='City: ')
entTel = ttk.Entry(root,state='readonly')
entCity = ttk.Entry(root,state='readonly')

with open('file.csv','r',newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter='\t')    


cb.grid(row=0,column=1)
labName.grid(row=0,column=0)
labTel.grid(row=1,column=0)
entTel.grid(row=1,column=1)
labCity.grid(row=2,column=0)
entCity.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind()` to execute function `on_select` when you select element on list.

```
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
```

and in this function you can fill `Entry`.

---

Old example from GitHub: [combobox-get-selection](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/combobox-get-selection/main.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---

def on_select(event=None):
    print('----------------------------')

    if event: # <-- this works only with bind because `command=` doesn't send event
        print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    for i, x in enumerate(all_comboboxes):
        print("all_comboboxes[%d]: %s" % (i, x.get()))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

all_comboboxes = []

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
cb.set("1")
cb.pack()
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

all_comboboxes.append(cb)

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
cb.set("A")
cb.pack()
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

all_comboboxes.append(cb)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Show all selections", command=on_select)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Line `if event:` in `on_select` works only when you use `bind()` because it executes function with information about event. `command=` executes function without arguments and then it sets `even=None` and then `if event:` is always `False`.

Comment: I tried the same in my code and this did not work.
In the 'if event:' condition the program is skipping and I'm using its same code.

def on_select(event=None):
    print('----------------------------')

    if event:
        print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

printing only '---------------'

Comment: do you bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` or use `command=` in `Button` ? `bind` executes function with information about event - and `if event` works, but `Button` execute it without arguments and then it sets `event=None` so `if event` is false.

Comment: My bad, I was using bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.on_select()) instead of self.on_select without ()
Thanks again!